# Is it possible to record data being passed from a program to a library or a function using DLL injection

Tags: dll-injection

Is it possible to use DLL injection to record the data passed in a function call and can this system be used for internal calls and external calls aswell? And how would one achieve that in rough terms?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's possible and relatively easy for external calls but difficult for internal calls. Of course either requires that you first manage to inject a DLL, somehow. As for the how, that's far too broad for an SO answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible. When a call is hooked, you can take the arguments and record as you like. For internal calls, you will probably need to know the VTables to hook those calls by their index in VTable.